# Sharepoint DateTimeControl hour reset on postback

Tags: datetimecontrol, viewstate

I have a SharePoint DateTimeControl inside of an UpdatePanel. 
The issue I am experiencing is that when a postback occurs inside the panel the hour section of the DateTimeControl always gets reset to 12.

I have EnableViewState set to true on the control but it still is reset on postback.

Does anyone know how to make this behavior stop happening?

```
<SharePoint:DateTimeControl ID="WorkshopStartField" runat="server" CssClassTextBox="textbox" EnableViewState="true"/>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this:
I added a hidden asp textbox, which the value does persist between postbacks, and when the hour dropdown changes i put the selected value into the textbox.
Then on page load of the panel I check if the value in the textbox is different than that in the hour dropdown and if it is I set the selected value in the dropdown to be what is in the textbox.
Super clunky, but it works.

```
$startHourSelectControl = $('#<%= WorkshopStartField.Controls[1].ClientID %>');
$startHourBox = $('#<%= StartHourHolder.ClientID %>');

if ($startHourBox.val() !== $startHourSelectControl.val()) {
   //if the start hour is different than the value held in the text box, then the page has posted back and lost the drop down value
   //set it back to what it was before the postback
   $startHourSelectControl.val($startHourBox.val());
}

$startHourSelectControl.change(function () {
   //if the start hour dropdown is changed, set the text box to have the same value
   $startHourBox.val($startHourSelectControl.val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a Microsoft bug in SharePoint DateTime Control.
 This DateTimeControl loses state during postbacks, specifically of the hour.
 I struggled a bit to get this work around because it doesn’t work even if I put enableviewstate=”true” in the control.
 However I happened to get this work by adding this line of code in a event that caused the postback. It could be any method/Event, in my case, it is SelectedIndexChanged event:

```
 if (dtcDateTime< DateTime.Today)
 {
 //Don’t do anything
  }
```

Just be doing this, it maintains the value of the control during postback.
https://spreflections.wordpress.com/2009/07/09/sharepoint-datetime-control/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I don't really understand how that would have worked, but I have so many things causing the page to panel to postback that I didn't want to add a bunch of javascript calls.